# R Markdown - First Attempt - Strange Error Message

Tags: r, r-markdown, revoscaler

I'm trying to create an R Markdown script for the first time today in RStudio. I have an existing R script which produces lots of graphs, and I'm hoping to use Markdown to produce `.pdf` files containing these graphs.

I started very simple:

````
```{r}

10 * 10

```
````

When I clicked on the "knit" button I saw an error message:

[image]

I ran `getOption("repos")` at the console and I saw:

```
"https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2019-02-01"
```

I don't know if it's relevant (I suspect it is): I'm not using standard R, I'm using Microsoft R Client 3.5.2 because I need access to the `revoScaleR` package.

I don't really understand what's going on here but it looks as if I'm using out of date stuff...can anyone help fix this please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh...I think I've fixed it:

```
options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cran.rstudio.com"))
```

Hoping this doesn't have any unintended consequences! *>crosses fingers<*